# Why does this Grammar work in LALR(1) but not LR(1)

Tags: parsing, lr-grammar, lalr, lr1

By all accounts, LR(1) should be more powerful in every way compared to LALR(1) since LR(1) builds a canonical collection of LR(1) items, and LALR(1) is just a better SLR(1) parser.

Then why does this grammar work successfully in an LALR(1) parser, but not in an LR(1) parser when I try this input:

`int + int`

For this grammar:

```
S' -> S
S -> Add

Add -> Mul
Add -> Add + Mul

Mul -> Const
Mul -> Mul * Mul

Const -> int
Const -> float
```

These are the JavaScript LR(1) and JavaScript LALR(1) parsers I used for this example:

<strike>http://jsmachines.sourceforge.net/machines/lr1.html</strike>

http://jsmachines.sourceforge.net/machines/lalr1.html

**UPDATE**

The JSmachine site is *pretty buggy*. I used this site instead https://zaa.ch/jison/try/usf/index.html from the University of South Florida, but I was advised to use Bison to ensure correctness.
As the top comment suggested, `Mul -> Mul * Mul` is pretty ambiguous so I updated the grammar accordingly

```
S' -> S
S -> Add

Add -> Mul
Add -> Add + Mul

Mul -> Const
Mul -> Mul * Const

Const -> int
Const -> float
```

adapted to BNF format:

```
%%
SS : S ;
S  : Add ;

Add : Mul
    | Add '+' Mul
    ;

Mul : Const
    | Mul '*' Const
    ;

Const : int
      | float
      ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "work" in your question. That online parser-generator reports shift-reduce conflicts for both the LR(1) and the LALR(1) algorithms, which is not suprising since your grammar includes the exponentially ambiguous

```
Mul -> Mul * Mul
```

Apparently, that site's LR(1) implementation handles errors with less grace than it's LALR(1) implementation. I'd say that it's a bug. But in any event, the grammar cannot produce either an LALR(1) or an LR(1) parser.

Comment: I'm kinda new to this, so I wasn't entirely sure what constitutes a conflict. 


The second Mul in: Mul -> Mul * Mul should've been Const now that I think about it. Thank you so much

Comment: @RaiyyanSiddiqui: My recollection is that jsmachines is not particularly reliable. Many online tools are buggy. But it does show the conflict: it's highlighted in the state table. If you want to definitely verify whether or not a grammar is conflict-free, you can install [bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html) on your own machine. Even if you don't ever compile the code it generates, it is still very handy to analyse your grammar. (See the --report command line option.)